# Copying multiple ranges in multiple selections

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dictionary of ranges (`groupRange`), in which I need to nudge the content of every cell in these ranges to the left.

The simple solution would be looping the dictionary like so:

**Option 1 - Too slow**

```VB
For Each x In groupRange
    Range(groupRange(x)).Copy Destination:=Range(groupRange(x)).Offset(0, -1)
Next x
```

The number of ranges varies, but it would usually be slow enough to cause major problems.

I tried `Union`, but quickly realized that copying and pasting multiple selections like that wasn't something Excel likes doing.

**Option 2 - Doesn't work**

```
Set r = Range(groupRange("G1"))
For Each x In groupRange
    Set r = Union(r, Range(groupRange(x)))
Next x
r.Copy Destination:=r.Offset(0, -1)
```

This just leaves me with the "cannot be used on multiple selections" error.

The only actually working workaround I managed so far, is just selecting every possible range so far (24 ranges), and everything in between. Then pasting it one column back.

**OPTION 3 - Best I have**

```
 Range("AF5:CY51").Copy Range("AE5")
```

This technically works, since everything in between is blank (at least for now) but I would love to avoid manipulating the cells I'm not using.

*I need to move at least the **value** and the **color** of the cells.*

**Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?**

I'm going to need to run this action in another loop, at least once per second. And I need to see the change in between each loop, since this is going to present data in real-time.

**Clarification**

Consider this to be the entire code, with the `printer()` sub being the one I need help with;

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
Public Const GrpAmount As Integer = 24

Public Function groupRange() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Static dict As Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        For i = 1 To GrpAmount
            dict.add "G" & i, "AF" & i * 2 + 3 & ":CY" & i * 2 + 3
        Next i
    End If
    Set groupRange = dict
End Function

Sub TimerLoop()
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 20
    Call printer
    Sleep 100
Next i
End Sub

Public Sub printer()
Dim x As Variant, r As Range
'Option 1
For Each x In groupRange
   Range(groupRange(x)).Copy Destination:=Range(groupRange(x)).Offset(0, -1)
Next x
'Option 3
Range("AF5:CY51").Copy Range("AE5")

End Sub
```

Comment: `range("a1").value=range("b1").value` is quicker than copying and pasting.

Comment: Do you need the formatting? might be a little quicker to just assign the values `Range(groupRange(x)).Offset(0, -1).Value = Range(groupRange(x)).Value`

Comment: Why do you have to populate your dictionary and then shift everything? Copying and pasting with union should work if you loop through the areas.

Comment: You can also consider using `Range.Delete` and deleting a single set of cells immediately to the left of your range with `Shift:=xlToLeft` as a parameter.

Comment: @SJR Would copy pasting with union AND looping be faster than just looping? And if so, how do I do that?

Comment: @ScottCraner I need at least the value and the background color. Even looping through only the values is noticeably slower, but maybe something I could live with.

Comment: Also, you will want to return the dictionary to another variable.  Every time you do `groupRange(x)` it runs the function again.  So that is two per loop.  load it into a dictionary variable outside the loop then refer to that.

Comment: Are you turning off screenupdating and calculation while running the "simple" version of your process?

Comment: @ScottCraner Not sure I'm doing it right, but when I set another dictionary to mirror my groupRange dictionary, there is no noticeable difference in speed.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not. I tried doing that, but even if I turned it on again at the end of the loop, the loop that loops the simple loop wouldn't update the worksheet each loop for some reason. Which is kind of the point.

Comment: How is your code triggered?  I've never seen turning screenupdating off cause code not to run, but calculation could have some effect if your code is triggered on a calculation event...

Comment: @TimWilliams The code is triggered manually. It's just a loop that loops this code, followed by a pause (kernel32 sleep). But I need each loop between the pauses to draw on the screen. No matter how many times, in how many places I try to turn screen updating on again, it won't until the main loop has finished.

Comment: If you need to show each update then there's likely not much point in turning off screenupdating...   Unless you mean you need to show updates periodically, not at every single change.  Maybe throw in a few DoEvents if you need the UI to "catch up"   Might help to explain your higher-level goal here. since you seem to want it to run faster, but showing periodic refreshes seems counter to that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208275/discussion-between-christofer-weber-and-tim-williams).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
Public Sub printer()

    Dim x As Variant, r As Range, d
    Application.Screenupdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Set d = groupRange  'See Scott's comment above
    For Each x In d
       with Range(d(x))
          .Copy Destination:=.Offset(0, -1)
       End With
    Next x
    Application.Screenupdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    DoEvents 'catch up
End Sub
```

Bottom line though: Excel is not a great animation platform.

Comment: Unfortunately this runs very slow still. If we scrap the idea of using .copy, and use .value and whatever we need to bring the background color as well, it might just work.